# Input array contents into HTML with styles

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I save my array as a variable: `var arrayContents = contentData;`
and my array: `['content_1', 'content_2', 'content_3', 'content_4']`

So i've got my array, I then want to place it into my `HTML` which i've done via using `text` like such: `$('.container').text(arrayContents);`

I need to break my text up so it currently looks like: [image]

And i'm trying to get it to look like : [image]

How can I break my array up so each item drops onto a new line? As when I use `.text` I print the whole array as one not each separate item.

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop and add a `<br>` tag to go to next line:

```
var contentToInsert;

$.each(arrayContents,function(value){
    contentToInsert += value + "<br>";
});

$('.container').html(arrayContents);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use html() instead of text(), check this

```
var htm = '';

var arrayContents = ['content_1','content_2','content_3'];

arrayContents.forEach(function(item){
  htm += item + '<br />'; // break after each item
});

$('.container').html(htm);
```

Comment: Thanks man! This is what I was looking for, how come I needed to use `html` instead of `text`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `.text()` works with a string value. You passed an array, which leads the "engine" to call arrayContents.toString() to get a string from the array. As you can see [there](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp), this function separates each entry by a comma.

If you want to produce an output on one column, you have to generate HTML (as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34789305/4375327)), or editing the div object through javascript DOM functions ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnt4osrr/1/)) :

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayContents.length; i++) {

  var currentElement = document.createElement("DIV"); // "DIV" or block-type element
  var currentText = document.createTextNode(arrayContents[i]);
  currentElement.appendChild(currentText);
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(currentElement);
}
```

Be sure of what kind of HTML you want to produce.